# Grails Mongodb Embedded Documents ?Bug?

Tags: grails, mongodb, grails-orm, grails-plugin, gorm-mongodb

I have this simple model:

```
abstract class Info {
    ObjectId id
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
}
class Question extends Info {
    String title
    String content
    List<Answer> answers = []
    static embedded = ['answers']
}
class Answer {
    String content
}
```

Written this way, **answer** are embedded in **question** (and no **id** is maintained for **answer**). I want to maintain the **id**, **dateCreated**, and **lastUpdated** fields for every **answer**. So I try the following:

```
class Answer extends Info {
    String content
}
```

When I run a simple test case (save a question with 1 answer), I get the following:

```
> db.question.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ed81d47e4b0777d795ce3c4"), "answers" : [ { "content" : "its very 
cool", "dateCreated" : null, "lastUpdated" : null,  "version" : null } ], "content" : 
"whats up with mongodb?", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2011-12-02T00:35:19.303Z"), 
"lastUpdated" : ISODate("2011-12-02T00:35:19.303Z"), "title" : "first question", 
"version" : 0 }
```

I notice here that fields **dateCreated** and **lastUpdate** are not auto-maintained by Grails. Also **version** field was added but has a ***null*** value as well, but interestingly no **_id** field created (even if I defined **id** in **Info** class).

In a second scenario, I try this:

```
class Answer {
    ObjectId id
    String content
}
```

and I get the following output:

```
> db.question.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ed81c30e4b076cb80ec947d"), "answers" : [ { "content" : "its very 
cool" } ], "content" : "whats up with mongodb?", "dateCreated" : ISODate("2011-12-
02T00:30:40.233Z"), "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2011-12-02T00:30:40.233Z"), "title" : 
"first question", "version" : 0 }
```

This time, **id** is also not created for the embedded document. Any explanation for this scenarios ? Why there is no **id** property, and why **dateCreated**, **lastUpdated**, and **version** are ***null***? Is this intended to work this way, or is it a bug?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you post a link to the question thread posted on the Grails forum? Did your question ever get resolved?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing! Did you get any answer?

Answer (score -1):

this is probably due to how the grails framework does the conversion (the GORM module).
You may have quicker / better answers from the grails forum.
Basically it seems that some of the automatic behavior (fill in dates and objectid) is only done for the root object, not subobjects.
You can also checkout an alternative ORM based on morphia:
http://www.grails.org/plugin/mongodb-morphia

Comment: I've seen the ORM based on morphia,but I'd rather stick with the one sponsored by Springsource. I will make a post on grails forum, thankx for pointing that out.